# Loop row wise over dataframe and apply a if-else

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named "final" with five columns as shown below:

```
quest  opt1  opt2  opt3 opt4   answer
asdsf    as   pe    dsf  qqqq    A
asdsf    sa   pe    dsf  qqqq    B
asdsf    ee   pe    dsf  qqqq    C
.
.
.
2000 rows
```

What I want is if

```
final$answer[1] has A then final$answer[1] <- final$opt1[1]
if final$answer[1] has B then final$answer[1] <- final$opt2[1] 
final$answer[1] has C then final$answer[1] <- final$opt3[1]
final$answer[1] has D then final$answer[1] <- final$opt4[1]
```

...so on for all rows of the dataframe.

So I wrote below loop and if-else and though it works.
Please suggest a better option if available ?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(final)){

  if (final$answer[i] == "A"){

   final$answer[i] <- final$opt1[i];
                           }
else if (final$answer[i] == "B"){
final$answer[i] <- final$opt2[i];

}
else if(final$answer[i] == "C"){
final$answer[i] <- final$opt3[i];

}
else{
final$answer[i] <- final$opt4[i];
}
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `ifelse()`. The first argument is a logical condition, the second is a value if true, and the third is the value if false.

For example I think you want:

```
final$answer <- ifelse(final$answer == "A", final$opt1, 
                  ifelse(final$answer == "B", final$opt2,
                  ifelse(final$answer == "C", final$opt3, final$opt4)))
```

Also since R uses vectorized functions you don't need to loop through each row.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the long nested `ifelse` blocks, you can also use [`dplyr::case_when`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html). Each line within `case_when` is evaluated in order, and the last condition `TRUE` functions like `else`.

You can also do this within a [`dplyr::mutate`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) call to avoid all the `df$`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    final_answer = case_when(
      answer == "A" ~ opt1,
      answer == "B" ~ opt2,
      answer == "C" ~ opt3,
      TRUE          ~ opt4
    )
  )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   quest  opt1  opt2  opt3  opt4 answer final_answer
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>        <chr>
#> 1 asdsf    as    pe   dsf  qqqq      A           as
#> 2 asdsf    sa    pe   dsf  qqqq      B           pe
#> 3 asdsf    ee    pe   dsf  qqqq      C          dsf


# or, without mutate:

df$final_answer <- case_when(
  df$answer == "A" ~ df$opt1,
  df$answer == "B" ~ df$opt2,
  df$answer == "C" ~ df$opt3,
  TRUE             ~ df$opt4
)
```

Load data:

```r
df <- readr::read_table("quest  opt1  opt2  opt3 opt4   answer
asdsf    as   pe    dsf  qqqq    A
asdsf    sa   pe    dsf  qqqq    B
asdsf    ee   pe    dsf  qqqq    C")
```

Answer (score 1):

Also to avoid nesting `ifelse`, you can use matrix indexing. As so:

```
dat[c("opt1","opt2","opt3","opt4")][
  cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)), match(dat$answer, c("A","B","C","D")))
]
#[1] "as"   "pe"   "dsf"  "qqqq"
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- data.frame(quest = c("asdsf", "asdsf", "asdsf", "asdsf"), 
opt1 = c("as", "sa", "ee", "ff"), opt2 = c("pe", "pe", "pe", 
"pe"), opt3 = c("dsf", "dsf", "dsf", "dsf"), opt4 = c("qqqq", 
"qqqq", "qqqq", "qqqq"), answer = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```